# Fabric Instantiation Orderer Error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

When I try to instantiate my chaincode:
    `root@93272a1da547:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# 
    peer chaincode instantiate -n fabrep -v 1.0.0 -C mychannel`

I'm getting the following error:

`2018-06-19 07:51:52.831 UTC [chaincodeCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Get chain(mychannel) orderer endpoint: orderer.example.com:7050
Error: Error getting broadcast client: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport: write tcp 172.19.0.7:39868->172.19.0.6:7050: write: broken pipe`

Anyone knows what this means?

Comment: Can u specify how to recreate this issue? Probably cleaning the containers and restarting the network might work...

Comment: I figured it, I didn't change the chaincode name in startFabric.sh file. The error is resolved now